# How to use condition sentence with middleware to show tree menu Laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel, web

I'm trying to use conditional sentence using middleware to show or not a three menu with links, depending on if you're admin middleware or guest, 
My admin Middleware

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(Auth::user()->clave==='132066')
        {

        return $next($request);
    }
    return redirect()->guest("/home");
    }
}
```

I'm not using role column or anything just an specific value from table users

I tried the if sentence like this

```
@if(Auth::user()->clave='132066')
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById("adminsolicitudes").style.display="none";
</script>
```

But I'm consent that isn't working with Admin middleware
Any suggestions?  Thanks

Comment: is "clave" stored as a varchar or a text in the database?

Comment: clave field is stored like int

Comment: you are assigning `clave` by using a single `=`

Comment: Is there a way to use middleware in the if sentence? doing that making avaliable to all the admins? I have this in my if @if(['middleware'=>['auth','Admin']]) but apparently doesn't make anything